# Renaming a Mongo Collection in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

PHP's Mongo driver lacks a renameCommand function. [There is reference](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-282) to do this through the admin database. But it seems more recent versions of the Mongo driver don't let you just "use" the admin database if do don't have login privileges on that database. So this method no longer works. I've also read this doesn't work in sharded environments although this isn't a concern for me currently.

The other suggestion people seem to have is to iterate through the "from" collection and insert into the "to" collection. With the proper WriteConcern (fire and forget) this could be fairly fast. But it still means pulling down each record over the network into the PHP process and then uploading it back over the network back into the database.

I ideally want a way to do it all server-side. Sort of like an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... in SQL. This way it is fast, network efficient and a low load on PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I have just tested this, it works as designed ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/ ):

```
$mongo->admin->command(array('renameCollection'=>'ns.user','to'=>'ns.e'));
```

That is how you rename an unsharded collection. One problem with MR is that it will change the shape of the output from the original collection. As such it is not very good at copying a collection. You would be better off copying it manually if your collection is sharded.

As an added note I upgraded to 1.4.2 (which for some reason comes out from the pecl channel into phpinfo() as 1.4.3dev `:S`) and it still works.

Comment: This is what I used to do. But since I upgrade the mongo driver (to 1.4.1) it stopped working complaining about authentication. I have another machine still on the older mongo driver and it works still so I know it's not a database permission issue.

Comment: @EricAnderson I am on 1.4.2 and I do not get that problem

Comment: Maybe 1.4.1 specific. I found an issue related to it which provides a workaround using authSource at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-782. So now back to just using renameCollection. Thanks for helping me figure all this out.

Answer (score 0):

**Updates**:

- Removed my old map/reduce method since I found out (and Sammaye pointed out) that this changes the structure
- Made my exec version secondary since I found out how to do it with renameCollection.

I believe I have found a solution. It appears some versions of the PHP driver will auth against the admin database even though it doesn't need to. But there is [a workaround](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-782) where the authSource connection param is used to change this behavior so it doesn't auth against the admin database but instead the database of your choice. So now my renameCollection function is just a wrapper around the renameCollection command again.

The key is to add authSource when connecting. In the below code $_ENV['MONGO_URI'] holds my connection string and default_database_name() returns the name of the database I want to auth against.

```
$class = 'MongoClient'; 
if( !class_exists($class) ) $class = 'Mongo'; 
$db_server = new $class($_ENV['MONGO_URI'].'?authSource='.default_database_name());
```

Here is my older version that used eval which should also work although some environments don't allow you to eval ([MongoLab](http://www.mongolab.com) gives you a crippled setup unless you have a dedicated system). But if you are running in a sharded environment this seems like a reasonable solution.

```
function renameCollection($old_name, $new_name) {
  db()->$new_name->drop();
  $copy = "function() {db.$old_name.find().forEach(function(d) {db.$new_name.insert(d)})}";
  db()->execute($copy);
  db()->$old_name->drop();
}
```

Comment: MR will change the document structure between the two collections, and you should be able to "use" the admin database if you have the right auth

Comment: Yea, I realized I posted this prematurely as I didn't notice the structure change. I am currently trying to figure out how I can do a map/reduce without the reduce part.

Comment: It is not a problem with the reduce but fundamentally, internally, how MongoDB forms the resulting documents and writes them out. In fact you should never be running the reduce since you should only ever be returning one key per document and MongoDBs reduce does not run in such a case

Comment: The new version as well has no benefits over doing it normally in the mongo console. The only difference to doing it through PHP is that you don't pull that data across, but if that solves your problem...it is what you would have to do if your collection was sharded

Answer (score -2):

you can use this. "dropTarget" flag is true then delete exist database.

```
 $mongo = new MongoClient('_MONGODB_HOST_URL_');
    $query = array("renameCollection" => "Database.OldName", "to" => "Database.NewName", "dropTarget" => "true");

    $mongo->admin->command($query);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. The problem is that the renameCommand doesn't work always depending on the credentials and Mongo driver version. Running the command with the dropTarget was what I was trying to do. It just doesn't always work if you don't have privileges on the admin database or are using certain versions of the PHP mongo driver.